# Do the $n$-th roots of unity of an *arbitrary* field form a cyclic group?

Tags: roots-of-unity

Do the $n$-th roots of unity of an arbitrary field form a cyclic group?

Or stated differently, 
*can we always find a primitive $n$-th root of unity?* Because if we have this element we can generate the group $<\zeta_n>$, and we are done.

In particularly I'm interested in the case where $n$ is not a prime.

Comment: Yes, because $x^n = 1$ can have at most $n$ solutions for any $n$. Say if the roots of unity is isomorphic as a group to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/nn'\mathbb Z$, then $x^n=1$ has $n^2$ solutions.

Comment: @HwChu I understand that it can have at most $n$ solutions, because we have a polynomial ring over a field. But I don't get the point that you are making, can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean, for instance if $F$ is a field whose root of unity is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / nn' \mathbb Z$, then the equation $x^n - 1=0$ has at least $n^2$ roots (count the $n$-torsions in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / nn' \mathbb Z$), and this is absurd.

Comment: I didn't cover torsion groups yet. Is it a theorem that the group of $n$-th roots of unity are always isomorphic to a group $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / n n' \mathbb{Z}$? You say nothing about $n'$, what is this, or does some theorem state the existence?

Comment: It should be isomorphic to a subgroup of that. $\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$ is the largest you can get.

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: Every finite subgroup of a field's multiplicative group is cyclic.

Comment: Yes, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic.

Comment: Your two questions are not the same!  The group can be cyclic without there existing a primitive $n$th root of unity (it just won't be cyclic of order $n$).

Answer (score -1):

Some comments quote a theorem that any **finite** subgroup of the multiplicative group of any field is finite cyclic and hence has a generator.
This theorem applies to $n$-th roots of unity and so they form a cyclic subgroup and have a generator. But is that generator a **primitive** $n$-th root of unity?

The problem of existence of $n$-th roots of unity depends on the field. For example, if the field has $4$ elements, then all $3$ non-zero elements are $3$-th roots of unity and, aside from $1$ itself, all roots of unity are $3n$-th roots of unity. So if $k=3n>3$, then there exist $k$-th roots of unity, but none of them are primitive, because if they were, then number of $k$-th roots of unity would be $k$.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. As the question is merely about showing the existence of the $n$-th primitive roots. But as  someone already pointed out it would follow from the general theorem that every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is finite.

Comment: Or, even more concretely, there are no primitive $k$th roots of unity in $\Bbb R$ for $k\ge3$.